# SSL Error in net::HTTP.get

Tags: ruby, scripting, ruby-2.0, net-http

I'm trying to use ruby to do a search based on account 1234, but I keep getting an SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 certificate error.  The site is signed, but for some reason Ruby doesn't like it.  The certificate is properly signed, so I'm not sure why it's rejecting it.

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://secure.domain.com/api/account/1234?api_key"+key)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
puts response.body #this must show the JSON contents
```

Based on another suggestion I also tried, but received the same error.

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was due to Windows not having support for something like OpenSSL built in.  After installing the appropriate binaries onto the system it worked without error.